# Can a local file be deleted by a html button( integrating html button with javascript, jquery or anything else)?

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, flask

I have a html table which shows all the files present in a local directory.

[image]

There is a remove button which deletes corresponding row of the table. Below is the code for that:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#myTable").on('click','.btnDelete',function(){
         $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      });
  });
```

```html
<td><button type='button' class='btnDelete'>x</button></td>
```

But this button only removes the row from the table and as I refresh my page, it again shows that file because its still there in the working directory.

**What I want is to delete file from directory itself. So that next time when I refresh my webpage, it will not show that file again.**

**Is this possible to achieve this? Can I delete a file from my local directory using html button? If yes, please suggest how.**

P.S. Below is the code which I used to create the table:

```html
<table id="myTable" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Select One</th>
    <th>File Name</th>
    <th>File Size</th>
    <th>File Type</th>
    <th>Remove</th>
    
  </tr>
  {% for file in files %}
    <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="myRadio" id="data"></td>
      <td>
      <a href="{{ (request.path + '/' if request.path != '/' else '') + file }}" id="data">
          {{ file }}
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
          fileSize
    </td>
    <td>
      <p>pdf</p>
    </td>
    <td><button type='button' class='btnDelete'>x</button></td>
    </tr>

  {% endfor %}
</ul>
</table>
```

Edit 2: This is my working directory setup:

[image]

Files which I am showing in html table are under /uploads.

Comment: Define "local". Your php code can delete from the webserver. JavaScript and php cannot, however, access the client-side filesystem (I.e on the machine where the browser is running)

Comment: Actually I am new in web development and very basic idea of html css js. No idea about php. It will be real helpful if you can provide some reference where this particular functionality is been used. Thank you.

Comment: First you need explain more, as I  mentioned. Are you trying to delete files from the webserver? If so, you can google "php delete file" to get started. If you want to know how to tell php what file was selected for deletion, you need to know about forms. But don't bite off more than you can chew - if you've never used php before, then take some introductory tutorials to get used to the language in general, before you try to attempt specific tasks. That's the best way to learn

Comment: Oh sorry. Didn't get your comment at first. Local means from laptop. I want to delete files from my laptop's C drive directory to recycle bin. In my html table, I am accessing a local folder in my laptop where there are multiple files. These files are shown in html table as shown in the image below. Then I want to delete file from this folder to recycle bin.

Comment: `In my html table, I am accessing a local folder in my laptop`...how exactly? What code creates the table? As I said, JavaScript and php don't have access to your local filesystem. (Of course if you're running the webserver on your laptop for testing then php will have access, by coincidence, but a real website runs on a separate server, so you can't rely on that

Comment: Edited my question. That table is iframe tag which is running one flask route /files which is accessing the base directory present in my local and giving all the files to html table. Found this too in stack overflow. Hope it is making sense.

Comment: OK. Not sure why you tagged php then, it's not the same as python. But python is also a server side language, so you wouldn't use both that and php in the same application. And you've still got the same issue - in a real web application you can't delete files from the local folder

Answer (score 2):

Simple `HTML`/`Javascript` webpage page cannot delete files from the computer. Just imagine the havoc it could create if you'd visit a webpage and it deleted files from your computer...
However if you run a webserver with `php`or `nodejs` on the same machine, than it can be done.

If your objective simply hide file from the table, you could store the list of "deleted" files in `localstorage` and in the code that generates the table check each file against `localstorage` database. I'm not familiar with the type of template you are using, so can't really show you an example

Comment: I have updated my question with additional code on how I am getting files and listing them on html table. So it will be helpful if you can provide some basic code to hide removed files from the list when I refresh my page after removing files.

Comment: Ok, so it's not `html` with simple `javascript` you are using but `python flask`. Which is essentially a webserver. If this is an app that runs on local computer than you probably could delete files, but if it's a remote web page, than you still won't be able access files on client's machine.

Comment: So, is it possible to connect html button with python flask webserver and achieve the delete functionality?

Comment: @noobmaster yes you can, but as we've explained a few times, you can only delete file from the server. While you're just testing it on one machine, the server and the local happen to be the same, but that won't work if you deploy the application on a real server. If you're looking to make an application which can control local files, you should consider making a desktop application instead of a web application.

Comment: I am fine with deleting the file from one machine only for now. Can you provide me some reference code using which I will be able to delete files from my machine as I am running this application in my machine only for now? Thank you

Comment: @noobmaster you can google "python delete file" to get started. If you want to know how to tell python what file was selected for deletion by the user in the browser, you need to know about html forms and python/flask - again, tutorials are abundant on Google. We don't provide free tutorials here, nor do we provide recommendations for such 3rd party resources  (see the [help/on-topic]) and there's generally very little need for us to type things into search engines on your behalf, either :-). We can help if you get stuck having tried some code though.